# Find the number of solutions of the equations : $3^{\cos(x)}=\lvert \sin(x) \rvert$ and $x \in (-2\pi,2\pi)$.

Tags: trigonometry

Find the number of solutions of the equations : $3^{\cos(x)}=\lvert \sin(x) \rvert$ and $x \in  (-2\pi,2\pi)$.

I've tried matching the extreme limits on both sides of the equation, but didn't find anything promising. 
$$
3^{\cos(x)} \in\left[\frac{1}{3},3\right]
\\
\lvert \sin(x) \rvert \in [0,1]
$$
How do I solve such equations ?

Comment: I think you can use the intermediate value theorem combined with the fact that both functions are monotonic between the extreme values you have identified.

Comment: @DanBrumleve Intermediate value theorem ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem since the functions are continuous the graphs must cross at least once in between the extrema.  And because they are monotonic, at most once.

Comment: @DanBrumleve:  the graphs are not monotonic on this interval, but one can find subintervals where they are.

Comment: I used geogebra to find out the answer. It is 8. Four obvious solutions are $\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2},\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{-3\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 3):

A graph indicates eight solutions.  Four are $\pm \frac {\pi}2$ and $\pm \frac {3\pi}2$ where the value of both expressions is $1$.  You can then observe that at $-2\pi,0,2\pi, 3^{\cos (x)} = 3 \gt |\sin (x)|$, and at $-\pi, \pi,\  3^{\cos (x)} \gt |\sin (x)|=0$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set $y=\cos x$, hence obtaining $3^y=\sqrt{1-y^2}$ and $y\in[-1,1]$. Since $y=\pm1$ are not solutions, every solution for $y$ corresponds to to exactly four solutions for $x$, namely $\pm\arccos y$ and $\pm(2\pi-\arccos y)$

Now, $3^y$ is strictly convex, while $\sqrt{1-y^2}$ is strictly concave. So, the equation $3^y=\sqrt{1-y^2}$ has at most $2$ solutions. One is $y=0$. Since $\sqrt{1-(-1)^2}<3^{-1}$ and $3^{-1/2}<\sqrt{1-\frac14}=\frac{\sqrt3}2$, the other one is some negative real number $\alpha$ by IVT.